# How to boot from CD even if BIOS doesn't allow this?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios

Recently I've helped user who had such problem:

> I have really old machine that has no USB ports and it's BIOS doesn't allow to boot from CD. However, it has Windows XP onboard. How can I install another system on it?

Then, I've decided that solution deserves to be put as exemplary as I've not seen it here. Here is my manual:

- [VirtualBox Solution](https://superuser.com/a/735730/238619)
- VMWare Solution
- [Plop bootloader solution](https://superuser.com/a/735793/238619) with credits to [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek)

Comment: do you have an existing OS of any sort?

Comment: Yes. Really, it was not my problem. I updated my question explaining this.

Comment: In addition, I suspect mounting a running OS System partition and doing any sort of procedure to it might turn out to be potentially danagerous. I'm not sure *how dangerous* - It might be fairly benign if you already have it partitioned, to potential for total data loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's significantly simpler solutions to using a VM *just* to bootstrap an installation. I'd personally install [plop bootloader](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) - it chainloads your current bootloader, and lets you boot a currently unsupported device like a cd or usb key from it. Its much safer than using a VM (especially on a system with a single drive - 2 OSes, stomping over each other... at once... really?), and gives you much more flexibility in your boot options.

The download zip contains an installer for windows that you can use from XP

As an added bonus, it looks like something out of an old video game ;)

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
2. Create [virtual disk from physical drive](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk)

   Run as Administrator (probably you are already Admin):

   ```
   VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\path\to\file.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
   ```

   Refer for instruction to link given above if you are running Linux.
3. Create Virtual Machine

   - run Oracle VM VirtualBox as Administrator
   - Select *Machine → New* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
     [image]
     [image]
   - Attach `vmdk` file:
     [image]
   - Attach bootable ISO file or use physical device
     [image]
   - Set boot order as shown below
     [image]
   - Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to save settings
4. Start **Raw** and press <kbd>F12</kbd>. Choose CD
   [image]